# Detectar botón presionado DisplayAlert Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Necesito realizar una acción al presionar el botón OK de un display alert, he intentado los siguientes métodos que he encontrado por internet

DisplayAlert:

```
Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("ERROR", "No se ha podido conectar con el servidor, revise su conexión de red", "OK");
```

> tratando de convertir a bool la salida del display alert: "error en el código del display alert: no se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo Systen.threading.tasks.task en bool

```
bool answer = Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("ERROR", "No se ha podido conectar con el servidor, revise su conexión de red", "OK");
 if (answer) { //acción a realizar }
```

> tratando de convertir a bool la salida del display alert: "error el código if(answer): no se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo Systen.threading.tasks.task en bool

```
var answer = Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("ERROR", "No se ha podido conectar con el servidor, revise su conexión de red", "OK");
if (answer) { //acción a realizar }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, tienes que hacer tu llamada await, para esperar la respuesta del DisplayAlert, entonces el evento Tapped del botón debe ser async

```
    async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var answer = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Titulo", "Mensaje", "Ok", "Cancelar"); // Usar await para esperar la respuesta
        if (answer == true) // Si la respuesta es Ok
        {
            
        }
        else // Si la respuesta es Cancelar
        {     

        }
    }
```

O en caso de usar MVVM con Binding y Command, podría quedar así tu llamada al Display Alert

```
        public ICommand CallDisplayAlert
        {
            get => new Command(async () =>
            {
                 var answer = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Titulo", "Mensaje", "Ok", "Cancelar");// Usar await para esperar la respuesta
                 if (answer == true) // Si la respuesta es Ok
                 {
                
                 }
                 else // Si la respuesta es Cancelar
                 {     

                 }
            });
        }
```